# How to make with JTextField and JButton a menu with name filling functions?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So i am trying to make a Panel where the player configures the names of the players in a local board game.
I want them to be able to add players between 2 and 6 so by default i have made the panel show up 2 `JTextField` boxes for them to add names and under the second one there is a "+" button to add an extra player. But i dont know how to do that and how to perform such action, when the user presses the "+" button a new `JTextField` pops up for the player to add a new player name.

I am providing the code i am using for this particular panel but it is necessary i can provide the whole code for my window. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
private void setLocalPanel() {

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    
    // localButtonsPanel config
    localButtonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 10));
    localButtonsPanel.setOpaque(false);
    
    // nameBox1 config
    nameBox1 = new JTextField("Player name");
    nameBox1.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    nameBox1.setEditable(true);
    c.ipady = 10;
    localButtonsPanel.add(nameBox1, c);

    // nameBox2 config
    nameBox2 = new JTextField("Player name");
    nameBox2.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    nameBox2.setEditable(true);
    localButtonsPanel.add(nameBox2, c);
    
    // + config
    extraBtn = new JButton("+");
    extraBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    extraBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD,40));
    extraBtn.setOpaque(false);
    extraBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    extraBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
    extraBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
    localButtonsPanel.add(extraBtn, new GridBagConstraints());
    
    c.gridy = 0;
    localPanel.add(localButtonsPanel, c);
    
    // startBtn config
    startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    startBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    startBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD,40));
    startBtn.setOpaque(false);
    startBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    startBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
    startBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
    c.gridy = 1;
    localPanel.add(startBtn, c);
    
    // localBackBtn config
    localBackBtn = new JButton("Back");
    localBackBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    localBackBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD,40));
    localBackBtn.setOpaque(false);
    localBackBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    localBackBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
    localBackBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
    c.gridy = 2;
    localPanel.add(localBackBtn, c);
    
    setLocalActions();
}
private void setLocalActions() {
    
    // startBtn config
    startBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            startBtn.setForeground(new Color(200, 210, 10));
            startBtn.setText("> Start <");
        }
        
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            startBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            startBtn.setText("Start");
        }
        
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // nameBox1.getText()
            // nameBox2.getText()
            localPanel.setVisible(false);
            gamePanel.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    
    // localBackBtn config
    localBackBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            localBackBtn.setForeground(new Color(200, 210, 10));
            localBackBtn.setText("> Back <");
        }
        
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            localBackBtn.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            localBackBtn.setText("Back");
        }
        
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            localPanel.setVisible(false);
            playPanel.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

PS. the `localPanel` has a `GridBagLayout`.

[image]

Comment: Instead of text fields, I'd use a single `JList`. Adding components to a visible GUI requires special handling, but add new items to the model of the list and the toolkit will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `ActionListener` to a `JButton` and not a `MouseListener`. Refer to [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

When the `+` button is clicked, you want to add a new `JTextField` to the `JPanel` that contains the fields that allow the user to enter a player's name.

Here is code, adapted from the code in your question, that adds a `JTextField` when the user clicks the `+` button. Notes about the code appear after it.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PlayGame implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final int  MAX_PLAYERS = 6;
    private static final String  BACK = "Back";
    private static final String  PLUS = "+";
    private static final String  START = "Start";

    private ArrayList<JTextField>  playerNameTextFields;
    private GridBagConstraints  gbc;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPanel  localButtonsPanel;

    public PlayGame() {
        playerNameTextFields = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String actionCommand = event.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case BACK:
                // Add code to execute when user clicks 'Back' button.
                break;
            case PLUS:
                addPlayerNameTextField();
                localButtonsPanel.revalidate();
                localButtonsPanel.repaint();
                if (playerNameTextFields.size() >= MAX_PLAYERS) {
                    ((JButton) event.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
                }
                break;
            case START:
                // Add code to execute when user clicks 'Start' button.
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Not implemented: " + actionCommand);
        }
    }

    private void addPlayerNameTextField() {
        JTextField playerNameTextField = new JTextField(10);
        playerNameTextField.setName("player" + playerNameTextFields.size());
        playerNameTextFields.add(playerNameTextField);
        gbc.gridy++;
        localButtonsPanel.add(playerNameTextField, gbc);
    }

    private JPanel createLocalPanel() {
        JPanel localPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        localPanel.setOpaque(false);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets.top = 10;
        localButtonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = -1;
        gbc.insets.top = 10;
        localButtonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 200));
        localButtonsPanel.setOpaque(false);
        addPlayerNameTextField();
        addPlayerNameTextField();
        localPanel.add(localButtonsPanel, c);
        c.gridy = 1;
        JButton extraBtn = new JButton(PLUS);
        extraBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD,40));
        extraBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        extraBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        extraBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        extraBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        extraBtn.addActionListener(this);
        extraBtn.setToolTipText("Add another player");
        localPanel.add(extraBtn, c);
        c.gridy = 2;
        JButton startBtn = new JButton(START);
        startBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        startBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD,40));
        startBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        startBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        startBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        startBtn.addActionListener(this);
        localPanel.add(startBtn, c);
        JButton localBackBtn = new JButton(BACK);
        localBackBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        localBackBtn.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD,40));
        localBackBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        localBackBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
        localBackBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        localBackBtn.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridy = 3;
        localPanel.add(localBackBtn, c);
        return localPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        frame.add(createLocalPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Start here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new PlayGame());
    }
}
```

Note that when you call `setContentAreaFilled(false)` on a `JButton`, there is no need to also call `setOpaque(false)`.

Instead of `new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255)` you can use the constant `WHITE` in class `java.awt.Color`.

`GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout` are not the same. Refer to [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Rather than use a background image like you have done, I simply set the background color to dark gray.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help and i am gonna start working with what you said right away

Comment: I made everything you said and it worked perfectly.
I wanna ask you if you can help with the boxes, because now that i made it work, having them the one under the other looks kind of weird so i want them to be side by side and also have a "-" button which will reduce the boxes until its only 2 again.
PS. i want to "-" to be at the same line as the "+" button.

Comment: `localButtonsPanel = new JPanel()` and remove variable `gbc` entirely. You don't need it if you are not using `GrifBagLayout`.

Comment: And the button actions? I mean how can i arrange the buttons so the "-" and "+" are side by side above the "Start" button and also the "-" button what needs to have in the actionPerfomed?

Comment: @Kamora [Core JFC](https://www.amazon.com/Core-JFC-2nd-Kim-Topley/dp/013090581X), [Java Swing](https://www.amazon.com/Java-Swing-Marc-Loy-ebook/dp/B007Y6KIHI), [The Definitive Guide to Java Swing](https://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-Swing-Guides-Paperback/dp/1590594479)